# how to break it down audio into overlapping frames?

Tags: android, audio, frames, overlapping, fingerprint

i'm doing  an android app for music identification system like shazam. i have already done the automattically audio record part. next i need to break it down this audio file to overlapping frames as mentioned in Robust audio fingerprint extraction algorithm based on 2-D chroma research paper. please can anyone help me to do it.

that research paper explain about like this.

the audio signal is divided into overlapping frames with the
length of about 370 ms, and the frame shift is 1/32 of the frame
length. Second, power spectrum is obtained by performing FFT,
and then the energies for 33 non-overlapping logarithmically
spaced subbands (e.g., Bark Scale) covering the frequency range
from 300 Hz to 2000 Hz are calculated. Finally, hash strings
(referred to as subfingerprints) are computed from the subband
energies in each frame as follows:

ED(n,m)=E(n,m)-E(n,m+1)-(E(n-1,m)-E(n-1,m+1)) ---> (1)
and f(n) = [F(n,0),.....,F(n,31)] ---> (2)

In (1), denotes the th subband energy in the th
frame, and is the output difference. is the
32-bit subfingerprint of frame and is the th bit of
it.

is this the algorithm for dividing overlapping frames????

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish this yet? Showing your code would be helpful.

Comment: i want to make sure the algorithm which is used for this function...there is a algorithm like ED(n,m)=E(n,m)-E(n,m+1)-(E(n-1,m)-E(n-1,m+1)). but it says something about energy calculation. therefore i have some doubt about this algorithm

Comment: the audio signal is divided into overlapping frames with the
length of about 370 ms, and the frame shift is 1/32 of the frame
length. Second, power spectrum is obtained by performing FFT,
and then the energies for 33 non-overlapping logarithmically
spaced subbands (e.g., Bark Scale) covering the frequency range
from 300 Hz to 2000 Hz are calculated. Finally, hash strings
(referred to as subfingerprints) are computed from the subband
energies in each frame as follows:

Comment: ED(n,m)=E(n,m)-E(n,m+1)-(E(n-1,m)-E(n-1,m+1))                         
and f(n) = [F(n,0),.....,F(n,31)] is this the algorithm for dividing overlapping frames???